# Boost spirit grammar issue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have some simple code to parse some msg as below,

```
if (msgtype == BATSAddOrderMsg::longMsgCode)
    m_wire_msg = ( p_ts >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::longMsgCode)
                        >> p_orderId
                        >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::sideFlag)
                        >> p_shares
                        >> qi::as_string[qi::repeat(6)[qi::char_]]
                        >> m_price
                        >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::displayFlag)
                        >> qi::as_string[qi::repeat(4)[qi::char_]] )
                        [qi::_val = phi::construct<BATSAddOrderMsg>(
                                qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4, qi::_5, qi::_6, qi::_7, qi::_8, qi::_9)];
else if (msgtype == BATSAddOrderMsg::shortMsgCode)
    m_wire_msg = ( p_ts >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::shortMsgCode)
                        >> p_orderId
                        >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::sideFlag)
                        >> p_shares
                        >> qi::as_string[qi::repeat(6)[qi::char_]]
                        >> m_price
                        >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::displayFlag) )
                        [qi::_val = phi::construct<BATSAddOrderMsg>(
                                qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4, qi::_5, qi::_6, qi::_7, qi::_8, "")];
```

In the above, the long msg type is just the short msg type with one additional field `qi::as_string[qi::repeat(4)[qi::char_]]`

When I tried to refactor into the below,

```
auto shared = p_ts >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::longMsgCode)
                   >> p_orderId
                   >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::sideFlag)
                   >> p_shares
                   >> qi::as_string[qi::repeat(6)[qi::char_]]
                   >> m_price
                   >> qi::char_(BATSAddOrderMsg::displayFlag);
if (msgtype == BATSAddOrderMsg::longMsgCode)
   m_wire_msg = shared >> qi::as_string[qi::repeat(4)[qi::char_]] )
                       [qi::_val = phi::construct<BATSAddOrderMsg>(
                              qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4, qi::_5, qi::_6, qi::_7, qi::_8, qi::_9)];

else if (msgtype == BATSAddOrderMsg::shortMsgCode)
    m_wire_msg = shared[qi::_val = phi::construct<BATSAddOrderMsg>(                                
    qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4, qi::_5, qi::_6, qi::_7, qi::_8, "")];
```

The code would compile, but when i run my unittests, it would die with a runtime exception.

Anyone knows why this behavoir from Boost Spirit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `auto` safely with Spirit Parser Expressions. See e.g. [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909)

However, it also looks like

- Your "short" version just has a default value `""`, see [Assign default value to variable using boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833307/assign-default-value-to-variable-using-boost-spirit/42837701#42837701)
- You could avoid semantic actions perhaps ([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil))

Comment: Cool thanks! it works perfect. For the part about semantic actions being evil, can you give an example of how I should rewrite my example above?

Comment: @Danny not without your data types. However I have a zillion examples  on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20semantic%20evil

Comment: Let me post some more details in a short while.

Comment: could you please help take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741125/spirit-grammar-parse-issue