# Boost.Spirit.Qi grammar for default values in Boost.Fusion adapt struct

Tags: c++, grammar, default-value, boost-spirit-qi, boost-fusion

```
struct coordinate {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  coordinate,
  (int, x)
  (int, y)
  (int, z)
)

template <typename Iterator>
struct coordinate_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, coordinate(), ascii::space_type>
{
  coordinate_grammar()
  :
    coordinate_grammar::base_type(start),
    optional_x(-(qi::int_ >> ':')),
    optional_z(-('@' >> qi::int_)),
    start(optional_x >> qi::int_ >> optional_z)
  {
  }

  qi::rule<Iterator, int, ascii::space_type> optional_x;
  qi::rule<Iterator, int, ascii::space_type> optional_z;
  qi::rule<Iterator, coordinate(), ascii::space_type> start;
};
```

I would like to set `0` as the default value of `x`, and `1000` as the default value of `z`.

**Input --> Desired Output:**

- `200:400@300` --> `[200,400,300]`
- `200:400` --> `[200,400,1000]`
- `400@300` --> `[0,400,300]`
- `400` --> `[0,400,1000]`

How do I need to modify the rule syntax to provide a default value when a value has not been specified for the optional *(`optional_x` and `optional_z`)* parsers?

Comment: Pretty much a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833307/assign-default-value-to-variable-using-boost-spirit/42837701#42837701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to reconsider the notion of "optional"...

```
optional_x(-(qi::int_ >> ':')),
optional_z(-('@' >> qi::int_)),
```

As we know, the `-` prefix indicates this rule can be specified 0 or 1 times, thus making it optional.

However, we don't actually want to have an "optional" value. We want either the value that has been parsed OR a default value. This is not optional, it is quite simply one or the other.

By modifying the rule syntax, when can better describe our intent.

```
optional_x((qi::int_ >> ':') | qi::attr(0)),
optional_z(('@' >> qi::int_) | qi::attr(1000)),
```

Now when the option is processed, if you have not provided a value for `x` or `z`, then a value will be provided on your behalf by `qi:attr(...)`.